# Focus the first element on a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, html-table

When I add a new row to a Html table, I want to focus the first Cell of this row.

My current code is

```
$('table td').first().focus();         // focus on the first cell of the row
```

but this selects the first cell of the entire table. What is needed to get the first cell of the added row?

Comment: What does the code that adds the row look like?

Comment: if you want to highligh the first cell in a row you first need rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's saying, "Find the first `td` in `table`."

You want, "Find the first `td` in the last `tr` in `table`."

```
$('table tr').last().find('td').first().focus();
```

That's assuming the last `tr` is the row that was just added.

Comment: This is assuming the OP is appending the new row to the end of the table. Also note that you can shorten it to just `$('table tr:last td:first').focus()`

Comment: Thanks, Rory. Yeah, there are lots of better ways to do this, I just wanted to roll with the one closest to what OP originally had.

Answer (score 1):

If you add this row at the end of table you need to replace .first with .last in your code. But the best way is to do this when you add the row. For example:

```
$row = $('<tr>...</tr>');
$row.appendTo($container).find('td:first').focus();
```